# Count ForeignKey filed with filtering

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

Есть модель

```
class Exam(TimeStampedModel):
initiator = models.ForeignKey('users.User',
                              related_name='started_exams',
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
participant = models.ForeignKey('users.User',
                                related_name='exam_participations',
                                blank=True,
                                null=True,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
solo_mode = models.BooleanField(default=False)
start_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Мне нужно посчитать количество звонков юзера с `id=2` с юзером с `id=1` учитывая что в звонках мы оба можешь быть как инициатором так и участником
В таблице в данный момент 3 записи:

```
id  initiator_id  participant_id
1       2              1
4       2              1
5       1              2
```

Я пробовал так:

```
queryset.annotate(
        calls_count=(
            Count('exam_participations', filter=Q(exam_participations__initiator=self.request.user)) +
            Count('started_exams', Q(started_exams__participant=self.request.user))
        )
    )
```

Где `queryset = User.objects.filter(id=2)`

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь оба случая посчитать отдельно.

Это должно помочь.

```
value1 = Exam.objects.filter(initiator__id = 1, participant__id = 2).count() 
value1 = Exam.objects.filter(initiator__id = 2, participant__id = 2).count()
result = value1 + value1
```